Access website locally
ubuntu 24.04 server, apache2, and firefox I can open local website with "localhost" "127.0.0.1" and machine IP "192.168.0.20" but not with shock.pics or ISP assigned IP. I can access the "shock.pics"or ISP assigned IP off local network.
Actiontec router ISP assigned IP port forward to "192.168.0.20" which is assigned to the server in router.
I have 3 websites in the virtual host file, all of which can be loaded off network and HTTPS works.
I tried bind9, but wound up having to restore as it messed everything up. Thank you Timeshift. I also have Nextcloud running under one website that is accessible off network only. Even using Nemo to go to the file and right clicking to open file with Firefox I get File not found "file:///var/www/html/shock.pics/index.html".
dnsmasq, is it what I need??
I redid bind9, but it still did not work. At least I can still access out of network. I am sure I messed up the zone and resolve files.
Does anything stand out?
# /etc/bind/named.conf.local
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

# This is the zone definition. replace example.com with your domain name
zone "shocktography.pics" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/shocktography.pics.db";
        };

# This is the zone definition for reverse DNS. replace 0.168.192 with your network address>
zone "192.168.0.20.in-addr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.192.168.0.20.in-addr.arpa";
};


# /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};


$ sudo mkdir /etc/bind/zones
$ sudo nano /etc/bind/zones/shocktography.pics.db
// replace example.com with your domain name. do not forget the . after the domain name!
// Also, replace ns1 with the name of your DNS server
example.com.      IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
// Do not modify the following lines!
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
 )

// Replace the following line as necessary:
// ns1 = DNS Server name
// mta = mail server name
// example.com = domain name
shocktography.pics.      IN      NS              dns1.registrar-servers.com .
shocktography.pics.      IN      MX     10       mta.shocktography.pics.

// Replace the IP address with the right IP addresses.
www              IN      A       192.168.0.20
mta              IN      A       192.168.0.20
ns1              IN      A       192.168.0.20

$ sudo systemctl restart bind9




sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.0.20
options edns0 trust-ad
search shocktography.pics

dig shocktography.pics
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> shocktography.pics
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 6277
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 69b43c0dcd0e060d010000006734e115d3a0718d491680c2 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;shocktography.pics.        IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.20#53(192.168.0.20) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 13 12:25:41 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 75


@ThomasWard
Thank You for your help.
Here is my result after restart bind9, I even restarted the computer.
ken@federation:~$ sudo systemctl restart bind9.service
[sudo] password for ken:
Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xeu named.service" for details.

ken@federation:~$ systemctl status named.service
× named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-11-17 07:46:01 EST; 10s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
    Process: 5173 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5173 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CPU: 27ms
Nov 17 07:46:01 federation systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 17 07:46:01 federation systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 17 07:46:01 federation systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 17 07:46:01 federation systemd[1]: Failed to start named.service - BIND Domain Name Server.


The router you have probably doesn't have adequate NAT reflection which would permit the external IP to just work.  Are you trying to access this on just one computer or more than one on your internal network?

I would like to be able to access on 5 different computers on my network.

@kschockk64 you'll need a second system on your network to provide the DNS server functionality then, and I'll give you a document that you can use to set that server up.  THEN you can update the DNS settings on your computers to use that DNS server on your network and it'll then work.  However that will impact all computers on your environment.  Also your BIND server is misconfigured, so I'll have to write up something specific to that.

I was able to see webpage on local by changing host file. I am still trying to figure out bind9. Thank you.

I'll be posting later today with a basic guide to get you started.  But you'll still need a separate system to run the DNS on your network independent from any system that 'leaves' the network like laptops  or such.

@karel Thank you for making my post readable!!

Join this chat room - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156256/room-regarding-https-askubuntu-com-questions-1532852-access-website-locally - and I'll grant you access there to read/write.  Because my moderator diamond lets me do that.  I have followup steps I'll need you to run and information to provide and the chat room will allow us to do that without polluting edits or answers.  Debugging BIND is harder than just here so.

There are two problems here:

You want to serve the site inside and outside the network
Your router, etc. doesn't have proper NAT reflection, which is where it'd automatically translate the request to the public address and 'reflect' it back to the internal system.  This is very common in off-the-shelf routers.

Because you have the problem point #2, you have to do what is called split DNS which will have a different DNS record served inside the network than out.  And for that you need a full DNS server set up independent of any system that will 'roam' outside of your network.
Assuming you set that up properly, and properly point your system to USE the DNS server (DO NOT edit the server itself to use the DNS server, only the systems ACCESSING the site from internally), you'll have everything functioning.  I include quick instructions for this on Ubuntu 22.04/24.04 as well.

BIND9 configuration - The DNS Nameserver

This part forward assumes you are working with Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04 on the system that will be the 'full DNS server' on your network

What you have to set up is an authoritative DNS server for your shock.pics site, but then forward normally all traffic to other destinations.
This isn't actually hard to set up and you were on the right track, except there were some things you'd have to do going forward.

Install BIND nameserver. sudo apt install bind9
Setup zones. These should live in the bind data directory which by default is actually in /var/cache/bind.  You'll need one zone file for the shock.pics zone. You don't actually need a reverse DNS zone like you tried to configure, so create a configuration in /var/cache/bind/shock.pics.db, and put the following content in it:

$ORIGIN shock.pics.
$TTL 3000

@ IN SOA ns.shock.pics. noreply.shock.pics. (
    1        ; serial number of zone
    28800    ; refresh time period (seconds)
    7200     ; retry time period (seconds)
    864000   ; zone record expiry time (seconds)
    86400    ; min. cache time (seconds)
    )

@ IN NS ns.shock.pics.

ns  IN A  192.168.0.20
mta IN A  192.168.0.20
www IN A  192.168.0.20

@ IN MX 10 mta.shock.pics.


Configure BIND9 to be authoritative.  Add this to the end of /etc/bind/named.conf.local:

zone "shock.pics." {
    type master;
    file "/var/cache/bind/shock.pics.db";
};


Now set other options in DNS server to properly work and forward OTHER DNS requests outside of your network.  Adjust your /etc/bind/named.conf.options to look like this:

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };

    minimal-responses yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;  # Conform to RFC1035
    listen-on { any; };
    
    allow-query { 127.0.0.0/8; 192.168.0.0/24; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.0/8; 192.168.0.0/24; };
};

This will set up so that requests for other domains will be forwarded to Google DNS resolvers and then those responses will be handed to the requesting internal system from the BIND9 nameserver.  Additionally, it enforces that a system MUST be inside your network to make DNS queries to the server and to get DNS lookups from outside the configured zones.  Thus preventing mis-use.

Restart BIND9 - sudo systemctl restart bind9.service

Test if it works - dig @localhost SOA shock.pics. - this should return a DNS result and not an NXDOMAIN or SERVFAIL entry/error response.


If all else works, then great, time to configure your actual computers to point at this system.

Change DHCP settings on your router
You will want to go into your router and change the DHCP settings so that when it hands out DNS servers, it puts your DNS server in the list of servers for your computers to use.  Unfortunately, that configuration is beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu as it varies from router to router.
If you are able to get into yout Router's administration panel and change this, great.  If not, or it's some kind of managed router that you yourself do not have the ability to configure to that level, then use the next section which explains how to configure DNS on your systems themselves.

Point your endpoint computers at the nameserver
This will depend on the OS in use, but you can edit your network configuration on endpoint machines to use custom DNS servers.  As the DNS server is assumed to have a static IP address you would use that in your config.
On Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04, if you run nm-connection-editor you can see your ethernet and wifi connections that're configured.

For your networks you care about (Archangel is one of the wifi networks I have for instance), edit its settings in the IPv4 Settings tab and set it similar to this (the freehand red arrows point at the settings to worry about, the IPv4 Settings tab is the same on Ethernet or Wifi networks):

Hit Save, then cycle your wifi connection (or reboot).  Once you're connected to your network, and you've removed the manual entry you put in your /etc/hosts file as you indicated you did, you can try to go to your site and it should just automatically work.

I don't have instructions for Windows or Mac on this, so you can search for "Change DNS server on Windows" or "Change DNS server on Mac" if you have those systems (or same for Android or iOS, etc.).


Pointing the computers in the network to the correct DNS server is best done in DHCP server, ie. in the router settings. Then the router will send the proper DNS server address to all the computers when replying to a DHCP request.

@raj There are a lot of routers out there that don't do DHCP in a way you can configure that. If OP's router is one of those routers, they are stuck with this method anyways.  That's simply because of the limitation of Routers.  I'll mention that in an edit shortly

It didn't work and I have an error. I tried to go to the chatroom, but it said i needed 20 points to chat. sudo journalctl -n 50 -u bind9.service
[sudo] password for ken:
-- No entries --

@kshockk64 That's because it won't let me add you to the room yet.  I'll do that again shortly now that you've tried to get in (and chat knows who you are).

The effect you are describing is totally common and expected.
I don't know the detailed specification of your router, but with most consumer routers the external IP address assigned to your router by your ISP (which is then port-forwarded to your web server) is meant to be accessed only from external (Internet-facing) interface of the router and not from internal one. Within your local network, you are supposed to use internal IP addresses.
To be able to achieve what you want, your router must support a feature that is commonly called "routing on a stick". Why "on a stick"? Because you need to reach through the router, outside of your LAN, to access the external IP address of the router, and then the router has to be smart enough (and most routers aren't) to turn this request "by 180 degrees" back into your LAN. If you try to draw the route the packet has to go, you would see a "stick" going a bit out of your router and then back.
If your router doesn't support this, you're basically out of luck. DNS settings have nothing to do with this. What you can achieve with DNS, however, is to set up your internal DNS server that would reply to queries for from within your LAN only, and would return the internal IP address of your server, ie. 192.168.0.20 for shock.pics. Thus you will be able to use the shock.pics domain name within your LAN, but still you won't be able to use the external IP address.
I see you tried to do this. I have no possibility now to analyze your bind configuration or give you the configuration you need for the above. Maybe others will do this. However, there is another possibility that doesn't require a DNS server.
If you have only a few computers in your network, add the name shock.pics with the IP address of 192.168.0.200 to hosts file of every computer you want to access your website from (in Linux, this file is /etc/hosts, in Windows it's something like C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts if I remember correctly). If you add a name with an IP address to this file, it will be locally recognized by the computer in question without the need for DNS resolution.

that's the correct Windows filepath by the way good recollection
